# Datagridview Cells Styling with RTF string

Tags: c#, parsing, datagridview, rtf

I'm working on a **C#** application (windows form) which has a DataGridView which is saved in a database (each cell considered as a string). What I want to do is to add a button that will color the text (*or the cell BackColor*) in such a way that when I print (on a paper) my database content, the color stays.

What I was thinking is to convert the cell string to RTF but I don't really know how to do this for the cells **do not support RTF natively**. I'd like to avoid as much as possible changing the DataGridView to a rich DataGridView so I was wondering if i can just do something like add this string when I save a colored cell:

> "{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
>   {\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\cf1\f0\fs17 " + cell.Value.ToString() + "\cf0\f1\par"

The tricky thing is that when I open my application, I want to read each cell's string, and apply the RTF style to the cell style. For exemple I save a red cell which contains "hello", when I open my application I want the cell to be red, but when I print (paper again) I want the text to be red (so parse the RTF on open to separate the text from the format).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to say I found the correct RTF string, it is the following:

```
"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1036{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fswiss\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\\f1\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\cf1\\f0\\fs17 " + value + "\\cf0\\f1}";
```

When starting the application I just check if the string cointains the RTF header, then I just split the text to keep the value and apply style to the cell.

Comment: Hi Blowi, u seem to have great experience with RichText. Got problem **richTextBox** in VS (C#) value because sometimes richTextBox.rtf gives value which starts as  `{\rtf1\ansi\` and sometimes starts likes `{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\` for the _same content_ in _RichTextbox_ and i think that additional `\fbidis\` is not the correct tag.